# Error handling when array is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, nsarray

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self getLoadingTableCellWithTableView:tableView];

    RssItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RssItemCell"];
    // If break in here, url fetch maybe error or row is null
    RssItem *feed = [[self.manager.feeds objectForKey:self.manager.currentChannel] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = feed.title;
    cell.description.text = feed.description;
    cell.date.text = feed.date;
    // if any image enclosure at rss parse
    [cell.enclosure setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue,
                   ^{
                       UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:feed.enclosure];
                       [cell.enclosure  setImage:image];
                       [cell setNeedsLayout];
                   });

    return cell;
}
```

I have a problem when i try to fetch empty row of RSS (no post on my web category)

I want to show alert and automaticly go to main page.

Stuck in here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self getLoadingTableCellWithTableView:tableView];

    RssItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RssItemCell"];
    @try {
        NSLog(@"Trying to tetch");
        // If break in here, url fetch maybe error or empty row
        RssItem *feed = [[self.manager.feeds objectForKey:self.manager.currentChannel] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.title.text = feed.title;
        cell.description.text = feed.description;
        [cell.enclosure setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue,
                       ^{
                           UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:feed.enclosure];
                           [cell.enclosure  setImage:image];
                           [cell setNeedsLayout];
                       });

        return cell;

    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"catching %@ reason %@", [e name], [e reason]);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",e] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        TableViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finally");
    }
}
```

Alert not appear and go to break point. How should i handling this error?

Comment: The above code will always go to  view controller regardless array is empty or not

Comment: Did you try just having a condition on `feed == nil` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you must always return UITableViewCell* at `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Secondly, that is a bad practice in general (see the quote below) and in particular as you might show a few alerts and present `TableViewController` several times. And as a problem solution, it seems like there's no exception which makes me think `self.manager.feeds` is actually `nil`.

---

[Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html)

> You should not use a try-catch block in place of standard programming
>   checks for Objective-C methods. In the case of an NSArray, for
>   example, you should always check the array’s count to determine the
>   number of items before trying to access an object at a given index.
>   The objectAtIndex: method throws an exception if you make an
>   out-of-bounds request so that you can find the bug in your code early
>   in the development cycle—you should avoid throwing exceptions in an
>   app that you ship to users.
>
> For more information on exceptions in Objective-C applications, see
>   [Exception Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012i).